# unit test : comparing file generation assertion returns false

Tags: java, unit-testing

I try to write my unit test to test my xlsx file generation.
I store a valid file in test resources, then try to generate the same file and compare them.

```
InputStream xlsxContent = xlsxContentWriter.generateXlsx(getSamples(10), RawEventDto.class);
InputStream file = new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.xlsx").toURI())));
Assert.assertEquals(IOUtils.toByteArray(file), IOUtils.toByteArray(xlsxContent));
```

Problem : assertion returns false.

To be sure that the generated file is the same than the file in resources, I saved the generated file itself in resources, so it's obviously the same :

```
InputStream xlsxContent = xlsxContentWriter.generateXlsx(getSamples(10), RawEventDto.class);           
File targetFile = new File("/home/user/test.xlsx");
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = xlsxContent.read(buffer)) !=-1){
      outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
xlsxContent.close();
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Any idea why this returns false? Any trick to know about file ?

**Edit :**

Here's my code now :

```
           InputStream file = new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.xlsx").toURI())));
        byte[] byteArray1 = IOUtils.toByteArray(file);
        byte[] byteArray2 = IOUtils.toByteArray(xlsxContent);


        Assert.assertEquals(IOUtils.toByteArray(file).length, IOUtils.toByteArray(xlsxContent).length);
        Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(byteArray1,byteArray2));
```

But I still getting assertion = false, actually I'm getting this error :

> java.lang.AssertionError: null    at
>   org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)     at
>   org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)   at
>   org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)   at
>   com.renault.hsmt.util.test.XlsxContentWriterTest.testXlsxWrite(XlsxContentWriterTest.java:61)

Actually, even this code returns false (I'm comparing generated file to itself, without taking it from resources folder) :

```
InputStream xlsxContent = xlsxContentWriter.generateXlsx(getSamples(10), RawEventDto.class);
            byte[] byteArray1 = IOUtils.toByteArray(xlsxContent);
            byte[] byteArray2 = IOUtils.toByteArray(xlsxContent);


            Assert.assertEquals(IOUtils.toByteArray(xlsxContent).length, IOUtils.toByteArray(xlsxContent).length);
            Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(byteArray1,byteArray2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You will not compare 2 byte arrays like this, use Arrays.equals instead, example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] a = {0,1};
    byte[] b = {0,1};
    System.out.println(a.equals(b)); //false
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(a, b)); //true
}
```

in your case it will be:

```
  Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(IOUtils.toByteArray(file), IOUtils.toByteArray(xlsxContent)));
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, I've edited my post, I tried your solution but still getting false assertion

Comment: Can you test with another assertion, before comparing arrays, which will compare length ? 

        Assert.assertEquals(IOUtils.toByteArray(file).length, IOUtils.toByteArray(xlsxContent).length);

Comment: Still not (I've updated my post again), still getting the null error

Comment: Seems that the lenght comparison is ok, but not the content comparison, this one raises the null error

Comment: Another one, compare byte after byte, if the're not same it will throw assertion error, with exact location in array:

   public static void compareArrays(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
        Assert.assertEquals(a.length, b.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            Assert.assertEquals("Bytes at " + i + " are different", a[i], b[i]);
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JUnit 5 you can just call

```
Assertions.assertArrayEquals(array1,array2);
```

[JUnit5 Assertions documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertArrayEquals-byte:A-byte:A-)